# Permission denied. Не пойму, в чем может быть беда

Tags: apache, apache2, apache2.4

Настройка виртуального хоста:

```
ServerName test.loc

ServerAdmin webmaster@test.loc
DocumentRoot /home/r/www/test.loc/web

ErrorLog /home/r/www/logs/test.loc/error.log
CustomLog /home/r/www/logs/test.loc/access.log combined

<Directory /home/r/www/test.loc/web>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Дополнительные настройки сервера (кроме тех, что были по умолчанию):

```
## Файл персональных настроек веб-сервера Apache от Razzwan-a

## Чтобы устранить предупреждение при перезапуске Apache (хотя в целом на производительности это не отразится)
ServerName test.loc

## Для того, чтобы Apache интерпретировал php и не предлагал сохранить php-файл
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml    

## Установка кодировки по умолчанию
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

## Настройка базовой директории
<Directory /home/r/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Права на папку, из которой грузится сайт (/home/r/www) 777.

И все равно выдает ошибку:

```
[Thu Dec 10 10:52:54.723123 2015] [core:error] [pid ****] (13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:] AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/home/r/www') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
[Thu Dec 10 10:52:54.792334 2015] [core:error] [pid *****] (13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:] AH00035: access to /favicon.ico denied (filesystem path '/home/r/www') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path, referer: http://test.loc:81/
```

Apache пробовал запускать от того же пользователя, которому принадлежать файлы сайта - никаких изменений.

Что еще можно проверить, глянуть? Уже просто нет идей.

Comment: А Require all granted зачем ? Я не вижу что бы у вас были настройки аутентификации, которая выставит этот "granted". Может просто `Allow from all` сделать

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> filesystem path '/home/r/www') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path

у какого-то из компонентов в этом пути не хватает атрибута `x` для пользователя, от имени которого работает у вас *apache*.

исправить можно, например, так (на всякий случай добавляется и атрибут `r` — право на чтение):

```
$ sudo chmod +rx /home /home/r /home/r/www
```

---

> Require all granted

директива [*require*](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require) появилась только в версии 2.4 программы *apache*.

если у вас, как указано с помощью меток, версия 2.2, то следует использовать директиву [*allow*](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#allow). например:

```
allow from all
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло установить всем папкам права на чтение.

Comment: *на чтение и исполнение